# Is it possible to combine position relative and fixed on the same element?

Tags: css, css-position, navbar

I'am making a Navbar to a website and I want it to be fixed at the top , so that when I scroll down the navbar is still acessible.

However, the NavBar position is relative (**should be fixed , I know**) because I have absolute elements which are relatively positioned to it.

If I change the position from relative to fixed the navbar looks and background color fall apart.

You can see the code below :

CSS

```
#cabeçalho{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    height: 110px;
    }
    
    header h1{
        margin: 3px;
        color: white ;
        font-size: 55px;
        font-family:  Avantgarde, TeX Gyre Adventor, URW Gothic L, Georgia, sans-serif;
    }
    
    header p{
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif ;
        transform: translate(95px , -20px);
    }
    
    ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position : absolute;
        transform: translate(950px , -20px);
        
    }
    
    li{
        display: inline ;
        border: 1px solid white;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        color : white
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="cabeçalho">

  <header>
    <h1>Joana Bonvalot</h1>
    <p>Artista - Pintora Clássica<p>
  </header>

  <ul>
      <li><a href="HomePage.html">Página Inicial</a></li>
      <li><a href="Galeria.html">Galeria</a></li>
      <li><a href="Encomendas.html">Encomendas</a></li>
      <li>Contactos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to know if there is any way I can make the navbar element position fixed but also relative in order to make the absolute elements stay in place.

Comment: Could you your HTML code?

Comment: have you heard of `position: sticky;` ?

Comment: @meo I have tried ``` position: sticky; ``` but it doesnt do the trick , cause when I scroll down the navbar stays in the same spot.

Comment: @StepUp Yes , sir , edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) layout. If it is used, then it will be simple to make columns to be set like row. And then there will be no need to use `absolute` positioning. In addition, your `unordered list` can be responsive, if we use flexbox layout. So the code would look like this:

```css
.navbar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
height: 110px;
}

.left {
flex-basis: 50%;
}

header h1 {
margin: 3px;
color: white;
font-size: 55px;
font-family: Avantgarde, TeX Gyre Adventor, URW Gothic L, Georgia, sans-serif;
}

header p {
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 95px;
}

.right {
flex: 1;
align-self: center;
}

li {
display: inline;
border: 1px solid white;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
color: white
}

.horizontal-list {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.list-item {
border: 1px solid white;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
color: white;
}

.order-1 {
order: 1;
}

.order-2 {
order: 2;
}

.order-3 {
order: 3;
}

.order-4 {
order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <header>
          <h1>Joana Bonvalot</h1>
          <p>Artista - Pintora Clássica<p>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div  class="right">
        <div class="horizontal-list">
            <div class="list-item order-1">
               <a href="HomePage.html">Página Inicial</a>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item order-2">
                <a href="Galeria.html">Galeria</a>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item order-3">
               <a href="Encomendas.html">Encomendas</a>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item order-4">Contactos</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is  the most elegant solution ! Thanks

Comment: @izzypt I am glad that it helped to you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Put all the elemets in the `navbar` tag and give it style `position: relative` so the `absolute positioned` elements stays in the nav.
Put the `nav` element in the `header`, and style it `position: fixed`.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
      <header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Example</li>
            <li>Example</li>
            <li>Example</li>
            <li>Example</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="absolute-div">

        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather simple solution, when changing the position from `relative` to `fixed`, create and set a `width` style equal to `100%`.

```
#cabeçalho {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Yes , this one solves the problem in quite a simple way. lol
Thanks!